# Why in c++ is data member initialization throwing a compiler error

Tags: c++

I am currently working through a programming book for c++ I have my toolchain set to use 
MacOS X C Linker
MacOS X C++ Linker
GCC Assembler
GCC Archiver
GCC C++ Compiler
GCC C Compiler

My question is why does the programming book show data member initialization valid with this syntax:

```
int number{0}; //to initialize the variable
```

but when I use the exact same syntax it throws a compiler error and breaks my program,
if I switch the initialization to

```
int number = {0}; // to initialize the variable
```

the program compiles without errors or warnings

Here is an example:

```
/*
 * A simple Account object
*/

#include <string>

class Account {
public:

Account( std::string accountName, int newBalance ) :  name(accountName) {
    if ( newBalance >= 0) {
        balance = newBalance;
    }

}

// member function that sets the name of an Account object
void setName( std::string accountName ) {
    name = accountName;
}

// member function that retrieves the name of Account object
std::string getName() const {
    return name;
}
// add amount to data member balance
void deposit( int deposit ) {
    if ( deposit >= 0 ) {
        balance = balance + deposit;
    }
}
// return the account balance
int getBalance() const {
    return balance;
}

private:
std::string name;
int balance{0}; // this is shown as valid syntax but throws an error
}; // end class Account
```

Comment: Use `-std=c++11` or more.

Comment: Upgrade your compiler, and/or use appropriate compilation option. Your compiler either does not support the modern C++ standard, or requires optional compilation options to enable support for it.

Comment: setting the language dialect in eclipse to -std=c++11 fixed the problem thank you